# Close connection in PHP but keep executing script in live iis server

Tags: php, codeigniter, flush

i am working on php-codeigniter  i am using code for php script excution after connection close it working well in local server but not working in iis which is live server
this is my code

```
set_time_limit(0);
        ob_end_clean();
        ignore_user_abort(true);
       header("Connection: close\r\n");
       header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");  
        ob_start();          
        echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
        $size = ob_get_length();   
        header("Content-Length: $size",TRUE);  
        ob_end_flush();
        ob_flush();
        flush();   
sleep(20);
file_put_contents('c:/tmp.txt', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

thanks 
regards
srikanth bollineni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found answer ......

1>On the server main page, under "Management", select "Configuration Editor";

2>under "Section", enter 'system.webServer/handlers';

3>next to "(Collection)" click "..." OR mark the element "(Collection)" and, under "Actions" und '(Collection)' Element, click "Edit Items";

4>scroll down until you find your PHP version under "Name";

5>at the bottom, the Properties are shown an can be edited manually, including responseBufferLimit, which should be set to 0 for flush() to work.

just follwing this steps flush is working on iis..my problem is resolve